# Finding Values Until Regex

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract values from string. here is a sample string

"Sample string Name: Mosa Phone: 020202020 Email: email@domain.com the rest of the sample string"

The phone doesn't necessary to be sequence of numbers it could be like (00-98550-22) or (+025-588) or (92122/222)

The good news is that these fields are always consecutive either separated by tab, white space, or new line.

so I am thinking how can I make it find the fields until the next field is found, so we can say find Name: then continue until you find Phone:

I am trying to achieve this using regex

This is the code I already wrote, but each field is evaluated alone

```
    $namepattern = "/(Name\:\s[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+)/";
    $phonepattern = "/(Phone\:\s\d+)/";
    $emailpattern = "/(Email:\s([_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})))/";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this regex to match name, phone and email in one:

```
/Name:\s(.+)\sPhone:\s(\d+)\sEmail:\s([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-zA-Z]+)/
```

Here's a demo: http://regex101.com/r/uO4tF7

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already solve it you can find the solution down

Answer (score 0):

This will match the needed

```
    /Name:\s(.+)\s*Phone:\s(.*)\s*Email:\s([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-zA-Z]+)/
```